# I want to display message with v-model but it does not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am learing vue with laravel.
I want to display message in the input tag with v-model, but it's not working.

```
<div class="card" id="myAppId">
<p>@{{ message }}</p>
<input type="text" v-model="message" class="form-control">
</div>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/vue.js') }}"></script>
    <script>

        new Vue({
            el: "#myAppId",
            data: {
                message : 'Hello Vue Js'
            }
        });

    </script>
```

It display only `<p>@{{ message }}</p>` with an empty input field.

Comment: Do you want to display it inside input field as default value or somewhere else?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the vue.js file exists?

Comment: @Pranay i want to display the message inside input tag

Comment: @GeorgeHanson yup! vue.js exists.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @DecadeMoon nope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just initialize that v-model variable with the initial value. 
This should achieve what you are looking for:

```
data: {
     message: 'initial_message',
}
```